# Can I iterate over several dicts in succession without merging them?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

In python, let's say I have three dicts:

```
d1, d2, d3 = {...}, {...}, {...}
```

I need to iterate over each of them and perform the same operation:

```
for k, v in d1.iteritems():
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
for k, v in d3.iteritems():
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
for k, v in d3.iteritems():
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
```

Is there a way to do this in one loop, such that each dictionary is iterated over in succession?  Something like this, but the syntax is obviously incorrect here:

```
for k, v in d1.iteritems(), d2.iteritems(), d3.iteritems():
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
```

I **don't** want to merge the dictionaries.  The best I can come up with is the nested loop below, but it seems like there should be "a more pythonic, single loop way."

```
for d in (d1, d2, d3):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        do_some_stuff(k, v)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

for k,v in chain(d1.iteritems(), d2.iteritems(), d3.iteritems()):
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
```

or more general

```
ds = d1,d2,d3
for k,v in chain.from_iterable(d.iteritems() for d in ds):
    do_some_stuff(k, v)
```

Comment: +1, I never noticed `chain.from_iterable` before. Cool. (But it may be worth noting that `for k,v in chain(*(d.iteritems() for d in ds)):` does almost the same thing in versions of Python below 2.6.)